# receive data from php:mysql to android using json

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am developing an Android app which sends and receive simple fname,Lname from my database. I am Using php and mysql for webservice. I am using this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)
In JSONParser class which is as following

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "talha");
        }
        Log.i("Buffer Error", "Baby Baby! Yes Mama! ");

        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.i("Buffer Error", "Eating suger! NO Mama! "+ json);




    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("MyJSON", "Error parsing data "+ e.toString());
    }



    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

When i am trying to parse string to json object

```
try {
     jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("MyJSON", "Error parsing data "+ e.toString());
    }
```

I am getting exception JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject. Please help since in every other tutorial, similar procedure is described.

Comment: So, What is error here ?

Comment: getting exception when it tries to parse to json object at jObj=new JSONObject(json);

Comment: Put Error log . Have you internet permission in menifest file ?

Comment: The error simply means that you are getting JSONArray as reply but you are trying to use it as a JSONObject. use new JSONArray(json)

Comment: can you show us the output at :  Log.i("Buffer Error", "Eating suger! NO Mama! "+ json);

Comment: yes, i Have permission. I am sending data from the same app which is working fine. Only facing problem in receiving Let me give a snapshot of error log. this is what i am getting in the error log->
Error Parsing Data org.json.Exception: Value [{key,value}] of type JSONAray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: i am getting this output at log.i("Buffer Error", "Eating suger! NO Mama! "+ json)-> [{"name":"value"},{"name":"value"},{"name":"value"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will get that problem if you will directly create that.Add one line after `json = b.toString();`

```
json = sb.toString();
json = "{json_parse" + "[" + json + "]" + "}";
```

Comment: Now i am getting this exception->  Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after json_parse at character 12 of {json_parse[[{"name":"fahad"},{"name":"talha"},{"name":"umer"},{"name":"ahmed"},{"name":""},{"name":"abc"},{"name":"ahmed perv"}]talha]}